# How to show a notification in the bar every hour?

Tags: android, notification-bar

i'm beginner in android and i don't know how to create a notification manager even my app is not running for example show a notify every hour .Any ideas?

Comment: AlarmManager (http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) + NotificationCompat (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Look into this..notification using **BroadcastReceiver**

http://karanbalkar.com/2013/07/tutorial-41-using-alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-in-android/

Hope it helps you.

Comment: thanks but if i want to parse a json file (if wifi is connected) what permission should i use (instead of myAlarmService)

Comment: MyAlaramService is Service not an permission..If you want to parse the data..you have to include the INTERNET permission and WIFI permission or ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE Permission.